# Loop over URLs and extract values and store in JSON JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of URLs I want to loop over and get the prices. I was doing it with Python but the website is blocking the script. I tried it with Chrome Dev. Tools and it was working fine. I do not have any experience with JavaScript to do it. I have a simple code where I want to loop over the URLs, extract the prices and store into a JSON file on my local PC like this.
Prices

```
{
'link': link,
'prices' span[class="price"],
'sku': td[data-th="SKU"]
}
```

Code:

```
const urls = [
    'https://www.fahorro.com/3-a-ofteno-1-mg-oft-5-ml-gotas.html',
    'https://www.fahorro.com/zamoprax-0-25-mg-c2-con-30-tabletas.html'
];

urls.forEach(function(url) {
    fetch(url).then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => console.log(data));;
});
```

Comment: So, what do you need ? The store to local code ?

Comment: Those URLs don't appear to be CORS-enabled, meaning you won't be able to do this with "normal" JavaScript in a website context, resp. you'd need to get a browser extension that allows you to overwrite CORS restrictions first.

Comment: I need to go to each URL and scrape the price as well as the SKU and store in a JSON file.

Comment: I thinking to run the code in chrome consol tab.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to parsing queries, I rely on the qs library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs). Can you please take a look at the package and see if can help you.

Comment: I don't think we will need JQuery since we can extract the values with plane javascript.